# Замена символа в div картинкой

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, хотел сделать так что бы в div символ :) заменялся смайликом(картинкой) но это не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не так и в чем проблема ? Заранее спасибо.

```
    <script>
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
function replaceEmotion (text) {
    var newText = text.replace(/:\)/g, '<img width="23" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCp1ny3sdYH4gFBlHFLEpvJcIiMq1VtZE1SiAjoe8B4AoPqbXd">');
    return newText;
}
document.body.innerHTML = replaceEmotion(text);
</script>
```

Вот как выглядит div

```
<div class="text" id="12"> Hello world :) </div>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName возвращает не текст, а коллекцию элементов dom, соответствующих имени класса. соответственно replace для этого списка делать бессмысленно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="text" id="12">Hello world :)</div>
<div class="text" id="13">Hello world :)</div>
<div class="text" id="14">Hello world :)</div>
```

**javascript**

```
//Получаем все элементы в массив
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("text");

function replaceEmotion(div) {
    //считаем количество div
    var div_total = div.length;
    //Заменяем текст внутри всех div с нужным классом
    for (i = 0; i < div_total; ++i) {
        div[i].innerHTML = div[i].innerHTML.replace(/:\)/g, '<img width="23" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCp1ny3sdYH4gFBlHFLEpvJcIiMq1VtZE1SiAjoe8B4AoPqbXd">');
    }
}
replaceEmotion(div);
```

Пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/EfGj2/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

при условии одного div

```
var text = document.querySelector('div.text').innerHTML;
```

или

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var l = divs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
if (divs[i].className == 'text') {
var text = divs[i].innerHTML;
break;
}
}

document.body.innerHTML = replaceEmotion(text);
```

а replaceEmotion впорядке